# Showing $\tan\alpha \tan\beta + \tan\beta \tan\gamma + \tan\gamma \tan\alpha = 1$ for positive angles with $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi/2$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $\alpha > 0$, $\beta > 0$, $\gamma > 0$ be three arbitrary angles such that $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi/2$. Prove that
$$\tan\alpha \tan\beta + \tan\beta \tan\gamma + \tan\gamma \tan\alpha = 1$$
Note: The argument must be valid for any triple of values of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ that satisfies the given conditions.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Hint: work out the general formula for $\tan(x+y+z)$ in terms of $\tan x$, $\tan y$, and $\tan z$; then look at its denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let alpha=a, beta=b and gamma=c.

a+b+c=π/2
=> a+b =(π/2-c)
=> tan(a+b) = tan (π/2-c)
=> tan(a+b) = cot c
=> tan(a+b) = 1/ tan c
=> tan c = 1/ tan(a+b)
We know,

tan(a+b) = (tan a + tan b)/(1-tan a tan b)
=>1/tan(a+b)=(1-tan a tan b)/ (tan a+tan b)

Therefore, tan c=(1-tan a tan b)/(tan a+ tan b)
On cross multiplying we get,

tan c(tan a+tan b) = (1-tan a tan b)
=>tan a tan b+ tan b tan c+tan a tan c=1
[PROVED]

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Well it's my first time writing an answer in Maths SE. I didn't realise I had to differentiate between a " low quality " question and a "high quality" question. I came, I saw a question and I answered. Also, while writing the answer I realized I had to learn some tools specific for this website to write the answer properly. So if only there was a "high quality" way to write questions and answers easily in this, could we satisfy the administrators. Anyway I won't be writing any questions or answers here without spending my "quality" time in thinking whether the quality was good.